# I did not deny permission but error is showing

Tags: geolocation, maps

I have the following errors in my flutter app:

> E/flutter ( 2893): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]
> Unhandled Exception: User denied permissions to access the device's
> location. E/flutter ( 2893): #0
> MethodChannelGeolocator.getCurrentPosition
> (package:geolocator_platform_interface/src/implementations/method_channel_geolocator.dart:127:7)
> E/flutter ( 2893):  E/flutter ( 2893): #1
> _RegisterScreenState.getCurrentLocation (package:megastore_sellers_app/authentication/register.dart:57:28)
> E/flutter ( 2893):  E/flutter ( 2893):
> I/TextInputPlugin( 2893): Composing region changed by the framework.
> Restarting the input method. D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 2893): The
> input method toggled cursor monitoring on

**My Code**

```
 getCurrentLocation() async
  {
    Position newPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
    );

    position = newPosition;

    placeMarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
      position!.latitude,
      position!.longitude,
    );

    Placemark pMark = placeMarks![0];

    String completeAddress = '${pMark.subThoroughfare} ${pMark.thoroughfare}, ${pMark.subLocality} ${pMark.locality}, ${pMark.subAdministrativeArea}, ${pMark.administrativeArea} ${pMark.postalCode}, ${pMark.country}';

    locationController.text = completeAddress;
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: getCurrentLocation() async
  {
    Position newPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
    );

    position = newPosition;

    placeMarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
      position!.latitude,
      position!.longitude,
);
    Placemark pMark = placeMarks![0];
    String completeAddress = '${pMark.subThoroughfare} ${pMark.thoroughfare}, ${pMark.subLocality} ${pMark.locality}, ${pMark.subAdministrativeArea}, ${pMark.administrativeArea} ${pMark.postalCode}, ${pMark.country}';
    locationController.text = completeAddress;

Comment: I have uploaded the code